# Links do not lead to right pages

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links, bookmarks

The problem is that the links (as well as the PDF bookmarks) of abstract, explanation, CV and appendix do not lead to the right pages. abstract leads to the `titlepage` and appendix to introduction etc. Also the sections belong to the introduction in the bookmarks :( Maybe it is due to the page numbering I did (and I need). I've tried so many things, I'm about to leave it like that :( Please correct my codes if you find the mistake. I'm a beginner and have a lot of difficulties to adjust the options, packages etc...

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{3em}  
\makeatother 

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[
colorlinks, 
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=black,
citecolor=black
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abbr,agsmcite,agsm,round]{harvard}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{portland}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
%\usepackage[subfigure]
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{10mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\harvardand{and}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\citeasnoun} 
\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}%
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
bla bla
\end{abstract}
\newpage

\phantom{T}\vspace{5,3cm}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
TEXT
\end{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage

\section*{Symbols}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Symbols}%
\newpage

\section*{List of abbreviations}
\begin{tabular}{L{5.5cm} L{9cm}}
\end{tabular}%

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of abbreviations}%
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}%

\section{Introduction}
text text text
\newpage

\section{System and whatever}
\subsection{System}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}  
\setcounter{section}{0} 

\newcommand{\initAnhang}{
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{section}\ \arabic{page}}
    \newpage
}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
        \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
        \renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{section}\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
        \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}}

\newcommand{\anhang}[1]{
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \input{#1}
    \newpage
}       

\appendix\initAnhang
\section{Appendix}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}%
\subsection{Descriptive Statistics}

\newpage

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\newpage

\section*{Explanation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Explanation}
\newpage

\begin{cv}{CV}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CV}%
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Create the missing anchors using `\phantomsection`; for example, `\pahntomsection\section*{Explanation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Explanation}`

Comment: Pass the option `pdfborder = {0 0 0}` to the `hyperref` pacakge to get rid of the borders around links.

Comment: I put hyperref last. pdfborder adds a first page (before title) and puts a comma in there. What's that? The red borders are still there.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from putting `hyperref` first and not last among the called packages I see nothing too bad in them; but are you sure you need all of them?

Anyway, I'd put `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel` first:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended for German
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}

<...other packages...>

\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  citecolor=black
  ]{hyperref} %% should be last

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{3em}  
\makeatother 

<...other settings...>
```

Your problem about wrong links is in the order of the commands:

```
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph} % not to get duplicate links (see Ulrike's comment)
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begingroup %% there will be no need to reset \abstractname
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
bla bla
\end{abstract}
\endgroup

\newpage

\vspace*{5,3cm} %% the space won't disappear at the top of the page

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\begin{abstract}
TEXT
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage

<...similarly for the other lists...>
```

With `\phantomsection` you set the link position; by putting `\addcontentsline` just after the page break you know that the reference to the page will be correct.

Comment: The title page needs also an unique page number format (e.g. with `pagenumbering{roman}`) or pageanchors should be disabled locally.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I always forget about that; fixed.

Comment: phantomsection works for all sections but Appendix. Tried it differently. But it does work for subsections of Appendix.

I also put \pagenumbering for the titlepage (before \titlepage). Doesnt change anything.

If I put hyperref last, the red borders just dont disappear with any options. pdfborder or colorlinks=true or whatever.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} makes the font grey/pale.

The sections of the main part are still in the bookmarks of introduction.

Comment: phantomsection works for the appendix, too, if I do it like you said:
\phantomsection\section{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
BUT, then my special pagenumbering for the appendix wont work (I want A1 etc) as shown in the minimal example.

Comment: @Anna Do *all* page numbers in the appendix be `A1` and so on, or should they change according to the appendix they're in?

Comment: I only have one appendix A. then I have subsections in this appendix that go A1, A2 and so on. I guess the setcounter{section}{0} is the problem. But I need it, otherwise the appendix would start with G and not with A.
The pagenumbers are A1, A2 and so on, do not dependent on the subsection.

Comment: `\phantomsection` solved it for me, thanks. Now I can graduate.

Answer (score 4):

Load `hyperref` as last package and then

```
...
\phantomsection
\phantom{T}\vspace{5.3cm}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
TEXT
\end{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\newpage
...
```

Comment: +1 for "Load hyperref LAST." That ought to be the first thing taught.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem. In my case of only one Appendix, this is sufficient:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}       
\setcounter{page}{1}

\newcommand{\initAnhang}{
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
    \newpage
}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
        \renewcommand\thesection{A}
        \renewcommand\thesubsection{A\arabic{subsection}}
        \renewcommand\thetable{A\arabic{table}}}        

\appendix\initAnhang
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Descriptive Statistics}
```

Instead of resetting the counter of the sections (that was the problem!), I just typed manually "A" to start the counting of the appendix, the pages and tables from "A" on.

The red borders of the links only disappear when putting `hyperref` before

```
\usepackage[abbr,agsmcite,agsm,round]{harvard}
```